# Writing multi-dimensional array into text file file

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, text-files, bufferedwriter

I have a task which involves passing array values (writing) into a text (.txt) file in Java. This is my first time using `BufferedWriter` and I've tried quite a few variations on `if` statements, but can't see to get my program to write in the format `matrix[i][j] + ","` until it hits the last column index and writes *without* the comma after the integer.

I tried using the `append()` method that `BufferedWriter` extends but I don't think I used it correctly.

**Current Code**

```
void writeMatrix(String filename, int[][] matrix) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                    bw.write(matrix[i][j] + ",");
            }
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

**Current Output**

```
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9,
```

I need the last digit on each line to **not include the comma** and `BufferedWriter` apparently doesn't like to add two `write()` methods together on the same line. So how could I do this?

Comment: The phrasing "passing an array into a txt file" is awkward.  Passing refers to handing a value or reference, often to a memory-resident data structure, to another process or routine, eg. passing arguments.  You don't "pass" a data structure to a persistent store such as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your innermost `for` loop to this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
    bw.write(matrix[i][j] + ((j == matrix[i].length-1) ? "" : ","));
}
```

This puts a simple ternary operator in that does this:

**`if`** `j` is last index:

- print nothing ()

**`else`**

- print a comma (`,`)

---

On request, this would be the equivalent to this `if-else` statement:

```
for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
    if(j == matrix[i].length-1) {
        bw.write(matrix[i][j]);
    } else {
        bw.write(matrix[i][j] + ",");
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! But I'm not sure I understand the syntax behind the question mark and colon, I haven't seen them used before?

Comment: It's essentially a shortened `if-else` statement. I'll put a simpler alternative up for you.

Comment: And welcome to the SO community (don't worry, your post was formatted ok)! I'm glad I helped (don't forget to accept), and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Compare matrix[i].length with j, then determine to print "," or not.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply add a if-else statement to decide to print the comma or not.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the if statement inside the iteration. if `j` is in the last column, it doesnt print the comma to your file, otherwise it does.

```
void writeMatrix(String filename, int[][] matrix) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if(j == matrix[i].length - 1){    
                    bw.write(matrix[i][j]);
                } else{
                    bw.write(matrix[i][j] + ",");
                }        
            }
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //why does the catch need its own curly?
    }
}
```

Hope it works!.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative that uses the (really powerful) Java Streams API.
For your case, the [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) method comes in handy. It only inserts delimiters between elements, so by default you don't get the trailing comma.

```java
void writeMatrix(String filename, int[][] matrix) {
  try {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

    for (int[] row: matrix) {
      String rowString = Arrays.stream(row)
          .boxed()
          .map(Objects::toString)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
      bw.write(rowString);
      bw.newLine();
    }

    bw.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Note: you could replace the outer `for` loop with another Streams API call: take a look at `forEach` in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). And there are many examples you can find online too.

```java
void writeMatrix(String filename, int[][] matrix) {
  String matrixString = Arrays.stream(matrix).map(row ->
      Arrays.stream(row)
          .boxed()
          .map(Objects::toString)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
      )
      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

  try {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
    bw.write(matrixString);
    bw.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

The Streams API is really elegant. The only issue you might find with this implementation is a stack overflow (excuse the pun :)) if the matrix is too large.